# Google OAuth 2.0 infinite authentification

Tags: php, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth

I'm trying to set up Management API using this Google tutorial: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/quickstart/web-php

I've downloaded index.php and oauth2callback.php files and edited URL to fixed addresses (I am using XAMPP, not terminal, and my files are in a subfolder).

I'm stuck in infinite redirects for Google authentication. It never shows me the output or any error.

index.php:

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ . '/client_secrets.json');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY);

if ($_SESSION['access_token']) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
  $analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);
  $profile = getFirstProfileId($analytics);
  $results = getResults($analytics, $profile);
  //printResults($results);
  echo $results;
} else {
  $redirect_uri = 'http://localhost/zen-analytics/management-api/oauth2callback.php';
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
...
```

oauth2callback.php:

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ . '/client_secrets.json');
$client->setRedirectUri = 'http://localhost/zen-analytics/management-api/oauth2callback.php';
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY);

if (! isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
} else {
  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  $redirect_uri = 'http://localhost/zen-analytics/management-api/';
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
?>
```

Web application authorized redirect URI is set to:

> http://localhost/zen-analytics/management-api/

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add info about which if/else blocks the requests go through? Possibly with values of relevant variables (`$_GET['code']`).

Comment: Those files are provided by Google so they should work. But they don't and I have no idea why. Otherwise I wouldn't ask :-(

Comment: Yes, I noticed, the code is almost the same as the one from Google, so if you don't include any additional info, it's hard to find the problem (since the code should be fine). You can add logging to your scripts or temporarily replace the `header()` calls with something like `echo 'Redirecting to ... because code is = ...'`.

Comment: The problem is in oauth2callback.php. Variable `$_GET['code']` sent by Google after successful login is always not set.

Comment: Very good, so check the URL you are getting and if you don't find a reason, post it here.